# 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error'

Tags: next.js, vercel, digital, envelope, routines

I have created an Nextjs app, when I try to host my app in vercel it shows this error.

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (C:\Users\tamil\OneDrive\Desktop\amazone clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:130015:18)   
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.digest (C:\Users\tamil\OneDrive\Desktop\amazone clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:129950:21)        
    at C:\Users\tamil\OneDrive\Desktop\amazone clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:53612:49
    at done (C:\Users\tamil\OneDrive\Desktop\amazone clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\neo-async\async.js:1:10308)
    at C:\Users\tamil\OneDrive\Desktop\amazone clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:126736:5
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\tamil\OneDrive\Desktop\amazone clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28712:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncQueue._handleResult (C:\Users\tamil\OneDrive\Desktop\amazone clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:126706:21)
    at C:\Users\tamil\OneDrive\Desktop\amazone clone\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:126689:11 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```